# Python routes not working for non-static URLs

Tags: python, routes, pylons, wsgi

I'm trying to write a unit test for an old `pylons` 0.9.7 application.
The issue we have is that it's very easy to accidentally hard-code URL
paths in our `jinja2` templates, which works fine until someone hosts
our application at a different prefix (i.e.- hosts it at
`http://localhost/foo/` instead of just `http://localhost/`). I'm
doing this using the default "functional test" setup that paste
created for me. I query every controller action, and pass in a custom
`SCRIPT_NAME` like so:

```
response = self.app.get('/some/url/path', 
                        extra_environ={'SCRIPT_NAME' : '/custom_prefix'})
```

I then use `beautifulsoup` to parse the document, iterating over all the
tags that have an `href` attribute or a `src` attribute, and ensure
that it starts with '/custom_prefix'.

Here's where things get odd: When we pass an absolute path in to
`pylons.url` (which is actually a `routes.util.URLGenerator`)in our templates like this:

```
{{ h.stylesheet_link(h.url('/css/style.css')) }}
```

...it works perfectly. However, when we call `pylons.url` with keyword
arguments like this:

```
{{ h.link_to('Home', h.url(controller='person', action='home')) }}
```

...the prefix is not inserted. However, the `url()` function works
correctly when running this correctly (i.e.- using `mod_wsgi` or
`pastedeploy`) with a non-empty `SCRIPT_NAME`.

I guess that I'm missing a critical step, but I can't think what it is.

Comment: If I understand it right, everything works just fine in real life, but you don't know how to make it work the same way in your tests?

Comment: Exactly. In real life everything works as expected. In my tests, non-static links don't get the SCRIPT_NAME prefix prepended.